# let `QWebView` scroll horizontally on mouse wheel

Tags: qt, qwebview

What's the easiest way to let a `QWebView` scroll horizontally instead of vertically on mouse wheel events. I can thinks of the following alternatives, but maybe there is some easier way:

1. subclass QWebView and reimplement `QWebView::wheelEvent()`
2. load some javascript on the displayed page which does the transformation

Answer (score 3):

Another method is to send a faked wheel-event with orientation Horizontal.

```
void HScrollWebView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *ev)
{
  QWheelEvent weHorizontal( ev->pos(), ev->delta(), ev->buttons(), ev->modifiers(), 
                            Qt::Horizontal );
  QWebView::wheelEvent( &weHorizontal );
}
```

This version also works for complex webpages. E.g. a webpage with a scrollable subsection will not scroll the correct area by calling

```
page()->currentFrame()->scroll(ev->delta(), 0);
```

if currentFrame() points at the wrong frame (e.g. the mainframe).

Answer (score 0):

I overestimated the complexity of option 1. in my question. I've implemented it now, like this (omitted constructor):

```
class HScrollWebView : public QWebView
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     explicit HScrollWebView(QWidget *parent = 0);
protected:
     virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *ev);
};

void HScrollWebView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *ev){
     page()->currentFrame()->scroll(ev->delta(), 0);
}
```